# While, does not exit

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm working on a project and am having trouble with it, I'm posting this program is similiar to what I'm working.

The problem is this: come in while the program does its function, then hangs and does not exit.

I've tried everything. Could anyone give any suggestions?

```
public class CommandZ {

    private static String Command;
    private static Scanner scan;


    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Shell: ");
            Command = scan.nextLine();

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-Command", Command);
            Process p;
            try {
                p = pb.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to start powershell");
                return;
            }

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            System.out.println("Begin!");
            try {
                //PROBLEM
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(line);                                       
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to read line");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Exit");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need another thread to read the process output, and then you join that thread at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can try. First off, you could read the spawned process's output from a separate thread. If you do this, make sure you set the `bufferedReader` as `final`:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // might need to try/catch round this
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);                                       
        }
    }
}).start();
```

and then just before the end of your program:

```
t.join();
```

to make sure that thread finishes its work.

The other option is to redirect the output of that process to the output of the Java program, using `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`:

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("powershell.exe", "-Command", Command).start();
```

Comment: ProcessBuilder().inheritIO()  Worked thx,  but i have new problem..

commands do not work with space,
and to always use a new command must have a line break

Comment: @MarcoRhayden Yes, you'd need to use `Command.split(" ")` to break up the arguments, and then pass the bits to the `ProcessBuilder` as appropriate, so that it knows that `a b c` is three arguments rather than one. (You should submit that as a separate question, though: it's not the same problem as this one, even if it's the same code.)

Comment: I did a while true, and this working.
but always when entering a new code
I first hit enter, I will work
to fix it!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the only thing you should change is where you define line. It would turn out like this :

```
  //Solution 
      string line = bufferedReader.readLine();
      if(line ==null){
        System.out.println("Empty document");
      }else{
        while((line!= null){
           System.out.println(line);
           line=bufferedReader.readLine();
     }
```

If you have Java 8, I'm going to refer you to this documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-

Hope my answer helps you out !